# JS Creating a Moving Landscape

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gsap, scrollmagic

Testing front-end to create my own interactive portfolio website: [marcelmp.x10host.com](http://marcelmp.x10host.com).

I'm trying to create my own story with a landscape with buildings and a moving car pinned on the container, all working based on scroll position. I'm using vanilla JS, JQuery, GSAP and ScrollMagic.

So how would you do the problem (given that I'm low to medium skilled programmer)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is worth to consider Mobile First Approach when developing anything in our days, especially a "Cool Design APP".

Additionally you might want to develop inside some online code editor, that you can share and ask people for opinion or help with individual issues.

Below is an LIVE example of your work embedded in a snipped.

You are welcome to clean up the Snipped and then correct your question(s), with an appropriate references to code that you have tried and maybe failed, or looking for a second opinion.

```js
$('body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
$(document).bind('scroll',function () {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});

//Controller Init
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();


//Var declaration
    const vw = window.innerWidth;
    //const vh = window.innerHeight;

    const menu = document.querySelector('#menu');
    const hello = document.querySelector('#hello');
    const mouse = document.getElementsByClassName('mouse');
    const about = document.querySelector('#about');

    const deskItems = document.getElementsByClassName('desk-items');
    const deskImac = document.querySelector('#deskImac');
    const deskKeyboard = document.querySelector('#deskKeyboard');
    const deskMouse = document.querySelector('#deskMouse');
    const deskBook = document.querySelector('#deskBook');
    const deskPen = document.querySelector('#deskPen');
    const deskPhone = document.querySelector('#deskPhone');
    const deskCoffee = document.querySelector('#deskCoffee');

    const story = document.querySelector('#story');
    const roadItems = document.getElementsByClassName('road-items');
    const roadSky = document.querySelector('#road_sky');

    let roadSkyWidth = roadSky.offsetWidth;


//Initial Animation
    TweenMax.set(about, {autoAlpha: 0});
    TweenMax.set(deskItems, {autoAlpha: 0});
    TweenMax.set(hello, {opacity:0});


//Timelines

    var menu_tween = new TimelineMax();
    menu_tween.to(hello, 2, {xPercent: -20, yPercent: 50, scale: 0.94})
        .to(about, 2, {autoAlpha: 1})
        .fromTo(deskImac, 2, {xPercent: 140, yPercent: -100, rotation: -7}, {
            xPercent: 162,
            yPercent: -10,
            rotation: 11,
            ease: Power1.easeOut,
            autoAlpha: 1
        }, "-=1.6")
        .fromTo(deskKeyboard, 2, {xPercent: 0, yPercent: -100, rotation: -15}, {
            xPercent: 128,
            yPercent: 38,
            rotation: 4,
            ease: Power3.easeOut,
            autoAlpha: 1
        }, "-=1.4")
        .fromTo(deskMouse, 2, {xPercent: 260, yPercent: -100, rotation: 0}, {
            xPercent: 195,
            yPercent: 68,
            rotation: 20,
            ease: Power3.easeOut,
            autoAlpha: 1
        }, "-=1.5")
        .fromTo(deskBook, 1.5, {xPercent: 20, yPercent: -100, rotation: 0}, {
            xPercent: 32,
            yPercent: -10,
            rotation: -6,
            ease: Power1.easeOut,
            autoAlpha: 1
        }, "-=2.2")
        .fromTo(deskPen, 1.5, {xPercent: 50, yPercent: -100, rotation: 199}, {
            xPercent: 34,
            yPercent: -16,
            rotation: 192,
            ease: Power2.easeOut,
            autoAlpha: 1
        }, "-=1.8")
        .fromTo(deskPhone, 1.5, {xPercent: 280, yPercent: 24, rotation: 0}, {
            xPercent: 230,
            yPercent: 32,
            rotation: -9,
            ease: Power3.easeOut,
            autoAlpha: 1
        }, "-=1.4")
        .fromTo(deskCoffee, 1.5, {xPercent: 75, yPercent: -100, rotation: -12}, {
            xPercent: 87,
            yPercent: -2,
            rotation: 4,
            ease: Power2.easeOut,
            autoAlpha: 1
        }, "-=1.3")
        .to(menu, 0.8, {delay: 0.8});

    var story_tween = new TimelineMax();
    story_tween.to(roadSky, 5, {
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        x: "-="+vw,
        modifiers: {
            x: function(x) {
                return x % roadSkyWidth;
            }
        },
        repeat: -1
    });

//Movement for Animations
    var sub_tween = TweenMax.to(mouse, 0.5, {yPercent:-25, autoAlpha: 0, opacity:0});

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".preloader").fadeOut('slow', function() {
            //Animation Init
            TweenMax.to(hello, 3, {opacity: 1});
            TweenMax.to(mouse, 1.6, {yPercent: -50, opacity: 1, delay: 0.5, autoAlpha:1});
            $(document).unbind('scroll');
            $('body').css({'overflow':'visible'});
        });
    });

//Scrolling Animation
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({offset: 1, duration: 850, reverse: true})
        .setPin(menu, {pushFollowers: false})
        .setTween(menu_tween)
        .addIndicators({name: "Menu"})
        .addTo(controller);

    new ScrollMagic.Scene({offset: 1, duration: 50})
        .setTween(sub_tween)
        .addIndicators({name: "Sub tween"})
        .addTo(controller);

    new ScrollMagic.Scene({offset:1600, duration: 500})
        .setPin(story, {pushFollowers: false})
        .setTween(story_tween)
        .addIndicators({name: "Story"})
        .addTo(controller);
```

```css
import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900');

html, body {
    background-color: #2196F3;  
    height: 100%;
}

.mouse { 
    /* Hide mouse */
    opacity: 0;
}

.preloader * {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -ms-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
}

.preloader {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    background-position: center;
}

#menu, #card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}

#menu h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 8.3vw;
    margin: 15% 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #E3F2FD;
    font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu h3 {
    margin: 20px 21vw;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 1.85vw;
}

#hello, #sub, #about {
    position: relative;
}

.mouse {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 22px;
    height: 42px;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -12px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
.scroll {
    display: block;
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 6px auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: white;
    -webkit-animation: finger 1s infinite;
    animation: finger 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes finger {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
        transform: translateY(20px);
    }
}
@keyframes finger {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
        transform: translateY(20px);
    }
}

.desk-items {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#deskBook {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
}

#road_trip {
    display: flex;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 50vh;
    background: white repeat-x;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 10vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#road_sky {
    top: 0;
    left: -1%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 400vw;
    background: url("Assets/road_sky.svg") repeat-x;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script
        src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/jquery.ScrollMagic.js"></script>

<div class="preloader"></div>


<section id="menu">

    <div id="hello">
        <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="sub">
        <div class="mouse">
            <div class="scroll"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="about">
        <h3>I'm Marcel Miró,<br>a self-taught Front End Developer,<br>student and tech enthusiast.</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="desk">
        <img class="desk-items" id="deskImac" src="//marcelmp.x10host.com/Assets/iMac.svg">
        <img class="desk-items" id="deskKeyboard" src="//marcelmp.x10host.com/Assets/keyboard.svg">
        <img class="desk-items" id="deskMouse" src="//marcelmp.x10host.com/Assets/mouse.svg">
        <img class="desk-items" id="deskBook" src="//marcelmp.x10host.com/Assets/moleskine.svg">
        <img class="desk-items" id="deskPen" src="//marcelmp.x10host.com/Assets/pencil.svg">
        <img class="desk-items" id="deskPhone" src="//marcelmp.x10host.com/Assets/iPhone.svg">
        <img class="desk-items" id="deskCoffee" src="//marcelmp.x10host.com/Assets/coffee.svg">
    </div>

</section>


<section id="story">
    <div id="road_trip">
        <div class="road-items" id="road_sky"></div>
        <!--<img class="road-items" id="buildings" src="//marcelmp.x10host.com/Assets/buildings.svg">
        <img class="road-items" id="car" src="//marcelmp.x10host.com/Assets/car.svg">-->

    </div>

<div id="road"></div>


<div style="height:200vh;"></div>

</section>
```